# What does Bruce Wayne pack on his third attempt of leaving the pit in Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-dark-knight-rises

Right before Bruce Wayne attempts to leave the pit he packs up something in a towel and wraps it around his body.

Does anyone see what he packs?

Comment: as far as I remember he carries the pack on each attempt, but we only see him packing it before his final one.

Comment: You must remember that on the first two attempts he used the rope to attempt the climb but on the third attempt he did not use the rope so even if he failed the climb he would be dead. It was do or die.

Answer (score 14):

When Bruce is packing up his stuff the doctor says the following to him.

> **Doctor:** "Ah supplies for your journey. Oh that's, that's wonderful!"

So I imagine it contains things vital to stay alive once he leaves the pit such as food and water.

Comment: So why doesn't he pack the first two times? Is he already assuming that he won't make it to the to and hence no journey and hence no supplies needed?

Answer (score 6):

He packs some food.  He's assuming he'll escape, but he needs provisions to survive on the surface, as he doesn't know where he is.

Answer (score 5):

**first time**

Bruce carries a bundle with him during the first trip. Although it is not shown what is it that he carries, nor is it mentioned in the Script.
[image: first time]

**second time**

This time Bruce does not carry anything, he simply walks determined to the ropeway and starts climbing.
[image: second time]

**third time**

```
      INT. CAVE PRISON - MORNING

      Wayne puts some scraps of bread into a rough coat which he
      folds into a makeshift shoulder pack.

                      PRISONER
       Supplies for your journey?
      Prisoners nearby laugh.
```

[image: third time]
From the picture one can assume that the folded brown packets are food items and the other is a water container. So basically, he carried sustenance with him - food and water.

Answer (score 4):

According to this copy of the [script](http://www.scribd.com/doc/104526560/198/INT-CAVE-PRISON-MORNING) (p. 127):

> Wayne puts some scraps of bread into a rough coat which he folds into
>   a makeshift shoulder pack.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers point out, he is packing supplies (bread).

**But why does he only packs in his third attempt?**

I think it's because only in this third attempt he was determined to escape and save Gotham, this emphasizes that he was not in the right mind set before.

Comment: While the second part of your answer is an interesting observation, it doesn't really answer the actual question. And the first part of the answer is (as you said yourself) already given by the other answers.